# Jest encountered an unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babeljs

Hej, I am trying to set up jest with some library. But when I try to test the library I am keep getting the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` error. Seems like he is not transpiling the node_modules, but I excluded it in the transformIgnorePatterns settings. I really dont know what to do and I am having pain to set it up. I am not using React nor Vue or something else.

My package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "MY-MODULE": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "babel-jest": "^24.3.1",
    "jest": "^24.3.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [ "@babel/preset-env" ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [ "js", "json" ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!MY-MODULE)"
    ]
  }
}
```

My testcase is something like this:

```
import { Test } from '../../src/Test';


describe('Test', () => {

    it('should work', () => {
        const test = new Test();
        expected(test).toBeDefined();
    });

});
```

and my Test.js is something like this:

```
import MyModule from 'MY-MODULE';

export class Test extends MyModule { }
```

Comment: Did you follow the setup on https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/babel-jest ? please share your `jest.config.js` and `.babelrc`  / `babel.config.js`

Comment: My `.babelrc` and my `jest.config.js` are both in my `package.json`

Comment: Try using Jest 23. Jest 24 changed the processor for file/glob matching to micromatch 3. This broke a lot of my regex in the Jest.transform

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I've downgraded it to 23 and it thrown an other issue: `Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3".`
It feels like babel 7 is not supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work for myself was to add:

```
   {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }
```

So that my presets read:

```
"presets": [
  [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }
  ],
```

This however appeared to mess with my development settings which included:

```
    {
      "modules": false
    }
```

So I included a separate babel 'dev' and 'test' environment:

```
  "babel": {
    "env": {
      "dev": {
        "presets": [
          [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
              "modules": false
            }
          ],
          "@babel/preset-react"
        ],
        "plugins": [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
      },
      "test": {
        "presets": [
          [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
              "targets": {
                "node": "current"
              }
            }
          ],
          "@babel/preset-react"
        ],
        "plugins": [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

I set the `NODE_ENV` in my scripts like this:

```
"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest",
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev concurrently \"webpack --watch\" \"electron .\"",
```

I am on Windows so I need to include `cross-env` which I believe is not required for other systems.